# It seems Phaser 3 throws "animationcomplete" notification twice for a single animation, how do I make it one?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I'm confused about the `'animationcomplete'` notification. I thought I would receive the notification one time when the animation I listen finishes. It turns out I will receive the notification n times. Here is the code.

```js
class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({ key: 'BootScene' });
  }
  preload() {
    this.load.spritesheet('brawler', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/photonstorm/phaser3-examples/master/public/assets/animations/brawler48x48.png', { frameWidth: 48, frameHeight: 48 });
  }
  create() {

    this.anims.create({
      key: 'win',
      frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('brawler', { frames: [ 30, 31 ] }),
      frameRate: 8,
      repeat: 0,
    });
    const cody = this.add.sprite(200, 70);
    cody.setScale(8);

    let btn = this.add.rectangle(500, 70, 200, 150, '#000')
    this.add.text(500, 70, 'click')

    btn.setInteractive();
    btn.on('pointerdown', () => {
      console.log('pointerdown');
      cody.play('win');
      cody.on('animationcomplete', (e) => {
        console.log(e.key);
      });
    });
  }
}

var config = {
  width: 800,
  height: 500,
  backgroundColor: '#555',
  scene: [BootScene]
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

I put two `console.log` in there, one for `pointerdown` and the other for `animationcomplete`.

First time I click the `btn`, I get one `pointerdown` and one `animationcomplete`. Second time I click the `btn`, I get one `pointerdown` and two `animationcomplete`.

How do I get just one `animationcomplete` no matter I click the `btn` n-th time?

Comment: `.on()` adds an event handler. You can have multiple event handlers for any event, even the same one multiple times. You add the `animationcomplete` handler from within the `pointerdown` handler. This means you're adding an additional `animationcomplete` handler every time you process a `pointerdown` event. Separate the two event handlers.

Comment: @Ouroborus I did think about this possibility though it cannot explain why it get one for each for the first time

Comment: Because you're also starting the animation when handling the `pointerdown` event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **@Ourobours** mentioned you are attaching, on each click, new event handler for `animationcomplete`.
An Since you can attach multiple event-handlers for the same event, all of them will be executed the next time it fires, ans so on.

You would only have to move the `animationcomplete` event-handler out of the `pointerdown` event handler function, and everything should work as you would expect it.

**Here a working demo:**

```js
class BootScene extends Phaser.Scene {
  constructor() {
    super({ key: 'BootScene' });
  }
  preload() {
    this.load.spritesheet('brawler', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/photonstorm/phaser3-examples/master/public/assets/animations/brawler48x48.png', { frameWidth: 48, frameHeight: 48 });
  }
  create() {

    this.anims.create({
      key: 'win',
      frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('brawler', { frames: [ 30, 31 ] }),
      frameRate: 8,
      repeat: 0,
    });
    const cody = this.add.sprite(200, 70);
    cody.setScale(8);

    let btn = this.add.rectangle(500, 70, 200, 150, '#000')
    this.add.text(500, 70, 'click')

    btn.setInteractive();
    
    cody.on('animationcomplete', (e) => {
        console.log(e.key);
    });
      
    btn.on('pointerdown', () => {
      console.log('pointerdown');
      cody.play('win');

    });
  }
}

var config = {
  width: 800,
  height: 500,
  backgroundColor: '#555',
  scene: [BootScene],
  banner:false
}

var game = new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```